# Xamarin.Forms (XAML): Different layouts depending on a condition

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to choose what layout initialize depending on one condition? I have a Grid for football stats but if `myViewModel.Sport == Sports.Basketball` I'd like to load a completely different layout.

I tried something like this with **Datatrigger** in each View but it seems a mess for me:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Goals}" 
       Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" 
                     Binding="{Binding Sport}" 
                     Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Text" 
                    Value="{Binding Points}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

I show "goals" but if the Sports enum value is 1 (Sports.Basketball) I change to "points". I want to do this with lots of Labels and even Images so I need a proper way to do it.

Could someone help me? I need to load a different Grid depending on the Sport Property of my ViewModel.

Comment: Why not push a whole different page altogether?

Comment: @Gerald my page is part of a TabbedPage. I think it shouldn't work, should it?

Comment: Another thing you could do is place each separate sport into it's own view, add all the views to your page and set their `IsVisible` property depending on which sport you want to show

Comment: Thanks @Gerald it works fine for me! I created one Grid for each sport and managed their visibility depending on the enum value.

Comment: I've upgraded it to an answer for you to accept :)

Comment: I'd use a DataTemplateSelector

Comment: I was reading about it yesterday and it seems exactly what I need, but all I found is Listview examples... Could I use it with `<DataTemplate><Grid/></DataTemplate>` @Stephane?

Comment: @HelioOjedaReyes - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52172669/199364

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another thing you could do is place each separate sport into it's own view, add all the views to your page and set their IsVisible property depending on which sport you want to show.

An example would look like this in pseudo-code:

```
<Page>
   <Grid>
       <BasketballView IsVisible="{Binding IsBasketball}">
       <SoccerView IsVisible="{Binding IsSoccer}">
       <FootballView IsVisible="{Binding IsFootball}">
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

Then set the appropriate boolean values from the ViewModel.

Comment: That could be expensive. The views might be created, even if not visible.

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix - if I understand correctly, they are created, but there is no layout call. I haven't noticed substantial delay (given compiled XAML and AOT on), when not visible, even for complex layouts. [However, anyone trying this technique, if they get a noticeable delay before page appears in release build, should test again with the invisible views completely removed, to see if that is the cause of delay.]

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix - ah, I hadn't read your comment on question, to use `DataTemplateSelector` instead. Yes, I see that is better approach for this. (Though I have encountered more complex situations, where it was easier to use IsVisible on parts of a layout, than to figure out how to do it with DataTemplateSelectors.)

Answer (score 0):

To use `DataTemplateSelector` to solve this, as mentioned by @StephaneDelcroix, you'll want a custom class that has `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate` properties.

I haven't thought through / tested how DataTemplateSelector would be used with this; anyone is welcome to add that to this answer.

```
using System.Collections;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    // From https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19874/listview-inside-stacklayout-a-height-problem/p2, @maxx313.
    public class TemplatedStack : StackLayout
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(TemplatedStack), propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);
        public IList ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }
        private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject pObj, object pOldVal, object pNewVal)
        {
            var layout = pObj as TemplatedStack;

            if (layout != null && layout.ItemTemplate != null)
            {
                layout.BuildLayout();
                layout.ForceLayout();
            }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(TemplatedStack), propertyChanged: OnItemTemplateChanged);
        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
        }
        private static void OnItemTemplateChanged(BindableObject pObj, object pOldVal, object pNewVal)
        {
            var layout = pObj as TemplatedStack;

            if (layout != null && layout.ItemsSource != null)
                layout.BuildLayout();
        }



        private void BuildLayout()
        {
            Children.Clear();

            foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
            {
                var view = (View)ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
                view.BindingContext = item;
                Children.Add(view);
            }
        }

        protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
        }
    }
}
```

In your XAML, do

```
<yourXmlns:TemplatedStack .../>
```

where `yourXmlns` must be an `xmlns` declaration at top of your XAML.

Usage of `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate` properties is similar to how you would bind an items collection and template to a ListView.
(The reason NOT to use a `ListView` here, is that ListView may interfere with touch events, and adds extra layout cost.)

Bind to this a collection containing a single item.
E.g. for this question, that item would be the specific sport being viewed.